# Flipping a descending value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to reverse the result I have here:

[image]

I know I have to use a sub query but its not working as my SQL codes is this:

```
SELECT MONTH(CaseTime) as 'Month', 
       COUNT(Case_ID) as 'Num' 
FROM `Case`
GROUP BY MONTH(CaseTime) 
ORDER BY CaseTime DESC LIMIT 6
```

MONTH(CaseTime) might be conflicting with the alias.

Current output is:

```
Month / Num
5 / 1
4 / 1 
3 / 1
2 / 1
1 / 18
12 / 13
```

Expect output should be:

```
Month
12 / 13
1 / 18
2 / 1 
3 / 1
4 / 1
5 / 1
```

Comment: How you want the result? Add the expected output.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 6`

Comment: @Ullas Sorry edit. It did not work properly as one of the date is taken away. But I would still like to know what does '1' stand for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Using phpmyadmin

Comment: @Brian : `1` stands for first column of the result set.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see, sorry. But yes, it should be MySQL.

Comment: @Ullas I edited my comment. It did not work as it does not take into consideration of the date format.

Comment: @Brian : I already commented for that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT MONTH(CaseTime) as 'Month', 
       COUNT(Case_ID) as 'Num' 
FROM `Case`
GROUP BY MONTH(CaseTime) 
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 6
```

**NOTE:** you may need a where clause for the `YEAR`

```
SELECT MONTH(CaseTime) as 'Month', 
       COUNT(Case_ID) as 'Num' 
FROM `Case`
WHERE YEAR(CaseTime) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH(CaseTime) 
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: I need to it take values from the latest date to six months before. I don't want to hardcode the value.